# How can I use Codenvy to run multiple published Docker Images?

Tags: codenvy

I would like to use Codenvy as a development and test environment for a project with published Docker images.

Here is a simplified version of the docker-compose configuration that I would like to replicate on Codenvy.

```
services:
  dspacedb:
    image: dspace/dspace-postgres-pgcrypto
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/pgdata

  dspace:
    image: "dspace/dspace:dspace-6_x"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "assetstore:/dspace/assetstore"
      - "solr:/dspace/solr"
    depends_on:
      - dspacedb
```

Based on my testing, I am unable to define volumes for my images. Fortunately, the Codenvy workspace persists the state of my containers between executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I have currently implemented.  I am curious to learn if there is a better approach.

1. Create a multi-machine stack that contains the desired images plus add an additional machine (eclipse/ubuntu_jdk8) to run the IDE.

   ```
   "recipe": {
     "type": "compose",
     "content": "services:\n dev-machine:\n  image: eclipse/ubuntu_jdk8\n dspacedb:\n  image: dspace/dspace-postgres-pgcrypto\n  mem_limit: 536870912\n dspace:\n  image: 'dspace/dspace:dspace-6_x'\n  mem_limit: 2147483648\n",
     "contentType": "application/x-yaml"
   },
   ```
2. Explicitly create a "server" for the container that I wish to expose with a public URL.

   ```
     "dspace": {
       "attributes": {
         "memoryLimitBytes": "2684354560"
       },
       "servers": {
         "dspace": {
           "properties": {},
           "protocol": "http",
           "port": "8080"
         }
       },
   ```
3. Create a workspace that uses this multi-machine image
4. After starting the workspace, look at the workspace configuration to determine the public URL for the service.

[image]

5. Codenvy sets up a common SSH key on each container in the workspace.  Using this key, I am able to transfer files between containers.